# git checkout branch to other working directory

Tags: git

I know I can checkout branch to other directories. I have work-tree parameter set like this `GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/example.com`, but how can I checkout a branch using '--work-tree' parameter? I've searched the manual but haven't found a reference explaining how to use it.

Comment: Did your check [this](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future references:

```
git --work-tree=/path/to/folder checkout -f my_branch
```